# Can I trust Solidity compiler to replace MOD with AND when possible

Tags: solidity, gas, compilation, optimization

According to the EVM Gas Cost Yellow Paper (can be found [here](https://github.com/djrtwo/evm-opcode-gas-costs)):

- The cost of `%` is 5
- The cost of `&` is 3

When `x` is a power of 2, the expression `a % x` is equivalent to `a & (x - 1)`.

If `x` is a constant variable, then this replacement can take place during compilation.

Can I trust the Solidity compiler to do this when optimization is enabled?

I am currently using `solcjs`, but the same question goes for `truffle`, `Remix IDE`, etc.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

From a quick test on Remix, it looks like enabling optimization does not get rid of the `MOD` opcode in the following code, so I believe the answer is "No, you cannot trust `solc` to perform this optimization."

```
contract Test {
    function test(uint256 x) public pure returns (uint256) {
        return x % 4;
    }
}
```